# Physics Circuit Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image]

The question asks

"How to voltmeter reading will change if the lamp Q is removed".

So I was thinking if lamp is removed, then the current flow to the voltmeter will increase thus increasing the voltmeter reading.

Am I wrong or is there a proper way to explain it through equations?

Comment: hint: can the resistance of of a pair of parallel resistors be larger than either?

Comment: There is ideally no flow of current through a voltmeter. Otherwise, adding the voltmeter to the circuit to measure the voltage would *change* the voltage and thus not measure correctly.

Comment: 1/R = 1/R1 + 1/R2
If removed one, Resistance increases?

Comment: @hyportnex, 'P' is only described as a "component", not a resistor. For example, 'P' could be a 4.0 V ideal voltage source. Or it could be a current source. In the 3 cases (resistor, voltage source, current source) you get 3 different answers to the question.

Comment: Resistance of P greater than resistance of parallel combination.....P will have a greater (share of the) pd OR R will have a lower (share of the ) pd..... Reading on voltmeter will increase

Comment: This is the answer, but I have no idea what it means

Answer (score 1):

The question can't be answered from the information given.

'P' is described only as a "component", not necessarily a resistor.

If P is, in fact, a resistor, then the voltmeter reading will increase.

But if P is an ideal voltage source, then removing the lamp would cause no change in the voltmeter reading.

Or if P is a current source, then removing the lamp would cause the voltmeter reading to increase.